# Login script on windows client does not map drives correctly

Tags: scripting, sles, novell, edirectory

This script is located in the OU container of a sample Organization tree in an eDirectory that  I created for the purpose of exploring and troubleshooting. This is not a critical/ live system setup.

But I am trying to get this login script to work however the script fails to mount any volume. I've defined the absolute volume path by logging into novell client as admin and mounting the folder manually and copying that path into the script. Still does not work.

The script has assigned trustees to all 3 groups in the tree. (browse)

The folders have assigned trustees to all 3 groups in the tree as well. (read/filescan)

Please highlight to me where the error is.

Even the %home_directory MAP command does not execute. When the user logs in through the client, the script only mounts the sys and public folders.

Please advice.

```
MAP DISPLAY OFF
MAP ERRORS OFF
MAP U:=%HOME_DIRECTORY
IF MEMBER OF "HR_ENS.Groups.Resources.ENS" THEN
MAP H:=\\ENS_TREE\.linux-7kgo_APPLICATIONS.Volumes.Resources.ENS\HR
MAP DISPLAY ON

PAUSE
END

IF MEMBER OF "SALES_ENS.Groups.Resources.ENS" THEN
MAP S:=\\ENS_TREE\.linux-7kgo_APPLICATIONS.Volumes.Resources.ENS\Sales
MAP DISPLAY ON

PAUSE
END

IF MEMBER OF "FINANCE_ENS.Groups.Resources.ENS" THEN MAP F:=\\ENS_TREE\.linux-7kgo_APPLICATIONS.Volumes.Resources.ENS\Finance
MAP DISPLAY ON

PAUSE
END
```